# How do I remove a package with "rU" status?

Tags: apt, dpkg, aptitude

I was trying to install some 32bit libraries with `dpkg -i --force-architecture` command. But it failed due to dependency problem.

Now if I try to install 64 bit version of the same library, it says it is already installed. If I try to remove it it says its not installed.

`dpkg-query -l` shows that the status is `rU` for the package.

I tried `dpkg-configure -a`, `dpkg--reconfigure`, `apt-get install -f`, `apt-get clean`, `apt-get autoclean` and basically every possible Google search.

How can I get out of this stuck package installation?

Comment: Does `sudo dpkg --configure -a` say anything? What's the full name of the package?

Comment: No, it doesn't say anything. libgtk1.2 is the full name of the package.

Comment: Can you post the full output of `sudo dpkg -r libgtk1.2`?

Comment: dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching libgtk1.2
Processing triggers for python-central ...

Comment: And the output of the attempt to install the 64bit version? And do you have any related files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`? (`ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgtk*`)

Comment: The output is:


dpkg: error processing libgtk1.2_1.2.10-18.1build2_amd64.deb (--install):
 libgtk1.2: 1.2.10-18.1build2 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with libgtk1.2:i386 1.2.10-18.1build2 (Multi-Arch: no) which is currently installed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgtk1.2_1.2.10-18.1build2_amd64.deb

I removed all the relating files from /var/lib/dpkg/info/

Comment: I tried install the 32 bit package again, and now dpkg --configure -a gives me the following error http://pastebin.com/vVNDcZRS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-arch packages should be suffixed with `:arch` where `arch` is `i386` or `amd64`. Try the i386 version of `libgtk1.2` by explicitly naming it:

```
sudo apt-get purge libgtk1.2:i386
```

If this fails due to dependency issues, try adding the `-f` option.

Where did you get these libraries from? The current GTK+ library is at 2.24-4 for Natty (libgtk2.0-0). libgtk1.2 can be found in Hardy and Dapper according to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgtk1.2).

Comment: The output is:
E: Unable to locate package libgtk1.2:i386
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgtk1.2'

I installed it from packages.Ubuntu.com as needed by Unreal tournament 2004 game.

Comment: This one worked:  sudo dpkg -r libgtk1.2:i386